# How can I set a disk quota for a group (vs a user)

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, ntfs, quota, disk-space-utilization

How can I set the disk quota for a group (vs. a single user) on an NTFS volume?

I'm using Windows Server 2003 SP2.

Comment: Not possible natively but I recall there were some third party products that provided that functionality back when I first started with Server 2000, so it may be worth investigating along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented to my unfortunately incorrect answer to your previous question - "Quotas only exist for users. My bad."

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but Windows 2003 **R2** introduced something called [File Server Resource Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755603(WS.10).aspx) which apparently gives you more options when it comes to quotas. In the original implementation, NTFS' quota support applied to users and volumes, not (sub)folders/groups.

**Edit:** just noticed you said **SP2** and not **R2**. Not sure if you actually have R2, but I'll leave this here anyway.